# Countdown calendar that tells how many days until a certain time when the CPU boots up

Tags: python-2.7

programmers! I have a question on how to make a countdown calendar until my piano recital; just as a fun side project. So, keeping that in mind, I created this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import numpy
import time
import commands
days = 59
(status, txt) = commands.getstatusoutput('date')
txt = txt.replace('EDT','')
txt = txt.replace('2016','')
if 'Mon' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Mon','')
elif 'Tue' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Tue','')
elif 'Wed' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Wed','')
elif 'Thu' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Thu','')
elif 'Fri' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Fri','')
elif 'Sat' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Sat','')
elif 'Sun' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('Sun','')

calc = int(txt) + days
while calc > days:
    days = days - 1
    if calc == days:
        print days
        break
    else:
        continue
```

However, in the variable date, it includes the time. I don't want the time, I just want the date. How could I do this? Also, please tell me what else is wrong with my code!
 - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime module to get the current date only. It will give you the current date without even so much modification on strings.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()
print str(now.month) + " " + str(now.day)
```

Comment: Yes, but this adds a few more problems. For starters, I cannot compare dates, which means I can't subtract from the variable 'days' and get my time until a certain date. The cause of this is that I can't convert datetime variables to floats or integers or strings. Finally, I can't modify the contents of the variable. More thinking is required.